# How to change text color in Angular Material 15?

Tags: sass, angular-material

I am using Angular Material 15, and defined a theme like so :

```
$blue-palette: (
  50: #e3f2fd,
  100: #bbdefb,
  200: #90caf9,
  300: #64b5f6,
  400: #42a5f5,
  500: #2196f3,
  600: #1e88e5,
  700: #1976d2,
  800: #1565c0,
  900: #0d47a1,
  A100: #82b1ff,
  A200: #448aff,
  A400: #2979ff,
  A700: #2962ff,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $light-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $light-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $light-primary-text,
    A400: $light-primary-text,
    A700: $light-primary-text,
  )
);
$my-palette: mat.define-palette($blue-palette, 500);
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme($palette);
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

But I would like to change the font color. It seems like Angular Material automatically defines the font color, black or white, according to my primary color. How do I change the font color ?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue in angular material itself, you can follow-up on this thread, once it's resolved, you will have your code working: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26056